# Program simulating water drops

Tags: java

1.This is what I have done in the program. My only problem is that it does not erase the circle that I create afterwards because I want it to have a fluid movement like a water wave.

```
 private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        int radio = 0;

        try {
            radio = Integer.parseInt(radio1.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. Introduzca un numero");
        }

        int x = evt.getX();
        int y = evt.getY();
        int x1 = x - radio / 2;
        int y1 = y - radio / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            jPanel1.getGraphics().drawOval(x1, y1, radio, radio);

            radio += 10;
            x1 = x - radio / 2;
            y1 = y - radio / 2;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            jPanel1.repaint();
        }

    }
```

Comment: english please.

Answer (score 0):

Java's GUI is single-threaded. Everything pauses for as long as the `jPanel1MouseClicked` method executes, so you cannot animate inside the method. It's the same as the familiar application hang/freeze while it is processing something large.

You need to start a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) from the constructor that can advance the 'state' of the animation and redraw.

Then you need to make one or more data structures to store all your past mouse coordinates along with a radius (radio?).

The timer should increase the radius of the circles and repaint *everything*. If the panel is opaque you can use that to your advantage.

(you'll probably want to remove coordinates that are too old or which radius is too large, otherwise memory grows unbounded)